# Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function on second call

Tags: javascript, function, typeerror

I have inherited some code, I am not allowed to change too much as my boss thinks it would be too much work (the site is truly, truly awful). There is a javascript function that is meant to play a sound `onclick` which it does fine the first time it is called but the second I get the `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function` error.

Here is the code, the variables are horribly named unfortunately:

```
    function FP_playSound(path) {
    var b, d = document, e, es, i, se = "<EMBED SRC='" + path + "' HIDDEN=TRUE LOOP=FALSE AUTOSTART=TRUE>";
    if (d.body)
        b = d.body;
    if (d.getElementsByTagName) {
        es = d.getElementsByTagName('embed');
        for (i = 0; i < es.length; i++) {
            e = es(i);
            if (e.src == path) {
                if (e.removeNode) e.removeNode();
                break;
            }
        } if (b != null && b.insertAdjacentHTML) b.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", se);
    }
}
```

and here is one of the calls:

```
<img id="img1" alt="" onclick="FP_playSound(/*url*/'sound/nikon-shutter.wav'); menue01_click(); " onmouseout="FP_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="FP_swapImg(1,1,/*id*/'img1',/*url*/'images/menue01_ro.png')" class="style2" src="images/menue01.png" />
```

There is no conflict with the naming of the function and any IDs. Is this something I should know about in javascript? Do I need to change the function or the calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
e = es(i);
```

That's trying to call `es` as a function, but `es` isn't a function, it's a `NodeList`.

It should be:

```
e = es[i];
```

...which retrieves the entry from the list for index `i`.

It doesn't cause trouble the first time, because the first time the list is empty and we never get to that line of code. The second time, because you added an `embed` element the first time, the list isn't empty and we reach this line, which throws the error (for good reason).

Comment: Thank you! I pointed out a similar problem to someone else the other day (in Python though) very annoying that I missed it. I will accept your answer as soon as I can. Cheers!